# Intuit and Curl

Tags: php, curl, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying data to access customer data with Intuit and Curl.

Intuit have excellent support for Java but not for PHP.

This is the code I have written, But it is showing 401 error
http://tny.cz/6f55d7bb

Comment: please put all relevant aspects of your question here. You never know about other hosting services and their availability.

Answer (score 0):

If the OAuth access token has expired, been revoked, or is invalid for some other reason, then the HTTP response code is 401.

So, can you please try to verify the access tokens.

If tokens are not valid, then please generate new keys and verify it using ApiExplorer tool

Key generation using openssl - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/007_firstrequest

After generating these keys, you can create a sample app with the public key. https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/009_using_customeraccountdata/0010_gettingstarted/0015_create_an_cad_integration

then use the .p12 file with pwd(if any) for SAML assertion in the apiexplorer tool - https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer

Let me know if it works for you.

Thanks

Comment: All this works for me, but then how do I use this setup outside of the API explorer? Not sure how to use the p12 file in PHP with CURL.